# Is there a C++ guideline to make first enum a "safe" default?

Tags: c++, c++03

I make the first enum a "safe" default value in my C++ code, but I cannot find an "official" guideline to quote to back up this practice.

Consider the struct:

```
struct MyNuke {
    enum {
        Detonate,
        Disable
    } state;
};
```

I'm using a C++03 compiler. I cannot add a constructor because the struct is used in a union. I cannot get rid of the union because that is not my code.

Calling the default constructor zero-initializes the struct members:

```
MyNuke nuke = MyNuke();
```

The value of nuke.state is now `Detonate`. `Disable` would be a safer first value.

It seems logical to make the first enum a "safe" value. Are there any C++ guidelines on this?

Comment: You can always provide a constructor that sets the members to what you want in the default case.

Comment: It seems that if you are worried about initialization, you should have a class with a constructor that contains asserts.

Comment: This is a common practice in C where you can't have constructors. You don't need this in C++. If you want to hunt down that guideline look at C guidelines.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify; this is not a C++11 compiler. As I wrote above, I cannot supply a constructor because the struct is used in a union.

Comment: The relevant guideline would be: "avoid unions".

Comment: There is no 'safe default' value without the application of a constructor. And with a constructor the order of the enum is irrelevant (outside of human readability or some other unspecified factor). For example, if Disable was the first element of your enum you are still not guaranteed that your object will be assigned it at instantiation without the use of a constructor.

Comment: `MyNuke nuke = MyNuke()` initializes `state` to zero. I'm still looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: The answer is write tests so that you're not using the wrong values in the first place. The "safe" default makes no sense; who is constructing one of these values, not caring what that value is, the using it? That's just a bug.

Comment: @pixelgrease: "*Perhaps I should clarify; this is not a C++11 compiler.*" Then this cannot be a question about the C++ core guidelines. Those guidelines are defined for more modern C++ standards; they do not deal in issues that only afflict C++03.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Thanks for that clarification -- I just removed the tag. When chosing tags I saw that "coding-style" was a landmine and avoided it. "coding-style" would have been more appropriate on multiple levels.

Comment: @Ðаn, yes. I need to convince my C++ team to stop using their favorite action verb as the first enum, but the C# guidelines won't win them over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no guidelines for this, as guidelines are not targeted to legacy code. To the contrary, they are targeted to code which will be written in five years. And as they clearly discourage usage of unions, they will not have a suggestion on how to add safe first value to the union.

However, in C++03 the question is valid, and the answer is what you are doing yourself. Since `X()` does value-initialize object and it's members, which is 0-initialization for enums, your enum will be initialized to first element (since it has value of 0 by default). However, please note that `X x;` does not do this, so the safety is not that great.

Comment: Thank you. Best answer so far. I may give up on looking for a C++ guideline on this C-code problem with a C++ compiler. It seems so obvious that I thought there must be a C++ guideline but I have not found it.

Comment: @pixelgrease: In my defence, my answer was a good one for the question you had posted at the time.

Comment: @pixelgrease: Why are you searching for C guidelines if you're writing C++?

Comment: @SergeyA, You identified the problem; I asked the wrong question. I researched this four different times with C++ in the query. Searching for: "c code style first enum" brings up many guidelines, one of which cited a C++ reference.

Answer (score 0):

From [possibility.com's C++ Coding Standard](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/CppCodingStandard.html):

> Make a label for an uninitialized or error state. Make it the first
>   label if possible.